# How do you show flymake diagnostics buffer only when there exists errors on emacs?

Tags: emacs, flymake

On flymake@emacs, there is `flymake-show-buffer-diagnostics` to show list of errors in new buffer.
I would like this to show up only when there exists errors in current buffer.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?